# Excel count from 10 to 10

Tags: excel, average

I have a table with 1000 rows , in each row there is a number value.

Is there any function so i can use make the average value of the first 10 rows , then the next 10 and so on... ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid volatile `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` set-ups (sadly commonplace) in favour of an `INDEX`-based one:

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,10*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,10*ROWS($1:1)))`

which is equivalent to:

`=AVERAGE(A1:A10)`

and, when copied down, gives results equivalent to, successively:

`=AVERAGE(A11:A20)`

`=AVERAGE(A21:A30)`

`=AVERAGE(A31:A40)`

etc.

Regards